# Why does using a range for loop gives different output than using a regular for loop in this scenario?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, vector, output

## What I would like to achieve

I intend to read inputs, then use cout to write out the numbers in input order separating them by ', ', except for the last one, which would end in a '\n'. The read ends form *cin* if not an integer/floating point character is put into it.

### The working code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Please enter double values. Enter an alphabetic character to stop reading in values.\n";

    std::vector<double> val;
    for (auto cur_val{ 0 }; std::cin >> cur_val;) {
        val.push_back(cur_val);
    }

    std::cout<<"Your values were:";for(auto i{0};i<val.size();i++)
    {
        if(i!=val.size() && i!=val.size()-1)std::cout<<val[i]<<", ";
        if(i==val.size()-1)std::cout<<val[i]<<'\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

*The output of this code is **3,4,5'\n'**, which is fine.*

### The code **not working properly**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Please enter double values. Enter an alphabetic character to stop reading in values.\n";

    std::vector<double> val;
    for (auto cur_val{ 0 }; std::cin >> cur_val;) {
        val.push_back(cur_val);

        std::cout << "Your values were:";

        for (unsigned int i : val) {
            if (i != val[val.size()] && i != val[val.size()] - 1)
                {std::cout << i << ", ";}
            if (i == val[val.size()]){std::cout << i << '\n';}
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

The output of this code is **3,4,5,**, which is not good.

Comment: Why compare i to val?

Comment: The braces and block comments in your second code are not valid. Please, create a valid example.

Comment: val[val.size()] - you are trying to access an element which is next after the last, this produces undefined behavior, the program can execue in unpredictable way.

Comment: @t.niese Yes, I see there is an extra comment ending left there I go and edit it now.

Comment: `val[val.size()]` will by definition go out of bounds

Comment: There is still a missing brace. I guess you mean `for (double cur_val{ 0 }; std::cin >> cur_val;) { val.push_back(cur_val); }` but the closing `}` is missing.

Comment: @GoverNator so does it solve if I compare it to val[val.size()-1]?

Comment: @BalázsBörcsök comapring `i` and  `val[val.size()-1]` would only work if the values are unique. If the user writes `1 2 3 1` it would not have the expected result.

Comment: @t.niese It clarifies things. So do you think that the most efficient way is to use a regular for loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`i` is declared as an integer So this comparison

```
if(i!=val[val.size()] ...
```

does not make sense and has undefined behavior because the vector does not contain an element at the position `val.size()`. Th valid range of indices is `[ 0, size() )`.

The vector stores doubles not integers.

In general the range-based loop is not suitable when you need also an index.

So you need to add one more variable that will signal whether a current value for example is the first or last value or not.

You can write the loop the following way

```
    bool first = true;        
    for ( const auto &item : val ) 
    {
        if ( !first ) std::cout << ", ";
        else first = false;

        std::cout << item;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
```

Or using your idea just write the loop like

```
    for ( const auto &item : v )
    {
        std::cout << item;
        std::cout << ( item == v[v.size() - 1] ? "\n" : ", " );
    }
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<double> v = { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.8, 9.9 };

    for ( const auto &item : v )
    {
        std::cout << item;
        std::cout << ( item == v[v.size() - 1] ? "\n" : ", " );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.8, 9.9
```

Take into account that this approach will work provided that the last element of the vector is not equal to any other element preceding the last.:) So maybe it is 
better to use the ordinary for-loop with an index.L)

Comment: in Bjarne's code std::vector is used to store doubles.

Comment: std::vector can store doubles. It is the i in `for (unsigned int i : val)` that should be changed to double.

Comment: Also, I had the intention to use i and compare it to the last value of val. Could you please help me understand, that why is it, that when the loop assigns val's last value to i it does not compare to the val.size()-th value to it correctly? Isn't the lvalue and rvalue supposed to be both the last value of val?

Comment: @SuvenPandey I will change it, but the compiler just warned for signed and unsigned int comparison.

Comment: `i == val[val.size() - 1]` is not equal to `i!=val.size()-1`. The one checks if the current value equals the last value in the vector, the second one checks if the index is at the end of the vector.

Comment: The last element is val[val.size()-1] not val[val.size()]. val[val.size()] may contain any random data.You should never compare i with val[val.size()]

Comment: Why do you use `const` at your 2. example? What is the role of `&` in it? @vladfrommoscow

Comment: @BalázsBörcsök & means a reference. That is this declaration const auto &item means that the values are not copied into the variable item. The variable is just an alias for each element of the vector.

Comment: I know this sounds lame, but is it like a "temporary storage"?

Comment: @BalázsBörcsök It is like a common alias for each element of the vector.

Comment: So if I understand it right it is a reference to the memory address of that given value of the vector.

Comment: @BalázsBörcsök Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for something like:

```
const char* sep = "";
for (const auto& e : val) {
    std::cout << sep << e;
    sep = ", ";
}
std::cout << '\n';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (unsigned int i : val) {
    if (i != val[val.size()] && i != val[val.size()] - 1)
        {std::cout << i << ", ";}
    if (i == val[val.size()]){std::cout << i << '\n';}
}
```

is equivalent to

```
{
    auto && __range = val;
    for (auto __begin = std::begin(__range), __end = std::end(__range); __begin != __end; ++__begin) {
        unsigned int i = *__begin;
        if (i != val[val.size()] && i != val[val.size()] - 1)
            {std::cout << i << ", ";}
        if (i == val[val.size()]){std::cout << i << '\n';}
    }
}
```

(see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

But `val` is a container that contains `double`s. `__begin` is an iterator to double. You should not use datatype `unsigned int` to store these values. You shouldn't compare `unsigned int` with `double` in line

```
i != val[val.size()]
```

In addition `val[val.size()]` goes out of bounds. This is undefined behavior.

Comment: Did you elaborate the range-for loop in details? I can not really understand it.

Comment: That's how a range based for loop works. For most structures in C++ there is basic equivalent. You can find them here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Comment: I know this is off topic, but understanding these components are very hard. Do you have any advice on how to better understand it?

Comment: If you don't understand range-based for loops you can transform them into basic for loops with this pattern. Every range-based for loop can be transformed into a basic for loop with this rule. But there is no generic rule to transform basic for loops into range-based for loops. What do you not understand?

Comment: The std::end and std::begin. I have never got to use them before.

Comment: `std::begin` calls `val.begin()` and `std::end` calls `val.end()`. These are iterators to the first resp. behind the last element. It's a little bit like `&val[0]` and `&val[val.size()]`.